# Error al mostrar dato de JSON con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo este JSON, llevo ya tiempo intentando acceder a adminArea6 que está dentro de locations, que está dentro de results, pero encuentro como, ya probé con `const results = responseJson.results[0].locations["adminArea3"].toString();` pero me devuelve `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`, alguien me puede ayudar? no entiendo mucho de JSON :c

Sé que es simple pero soy nuevo en esto y no sé casi nada de JSON

Necesito esto para un asistente de voz que estoy realizando, y quiero obtener el nombre de la ciudad, con la api de mapquestapi

```
{
   
   "results":[
      {
         "locations":[
            {
               "street":"Carlos Julio Arosemena",
               "adminArea6":"",
               "adminArea6Type":"Neighborhood",
               "adminArea5":"Calderon",
               "adminArea5Type":"City",
               "adminArea4":"",
               "adminArea4Type":"County",
               "adminArea3":"Pichincha",
               "adminArea3Type":"State",
               "adminArea1":"EC",
               "adminArea1Type":"Country",
               "postalCode":"170206",
               "geocodeQualityCode":"B1AAA",
               "geocodeQuality":"STREET",
               "dragPoint":false,
               "sideOfStreet":"N",
               "linkId":"0",
               "unknownInput":"",
               "type":"s",
               "latLng":{
                  "lat":'latitudX',
                  "lng":'longitudX'
               },
               "displayLatLng":{
                  "lat": 'latitudX',
                  "lng":'longitudX'
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let json = {
       
       "results":[
          {
             "locations":[
                {
                   "street":"Carlos Julio Arosemena",
                   "adminArea6":"",
                   "adminArea6Type":"Neighborhood",
                   "adminArea5":"Calderon",
                   "adminArea5Type":"City",
                   "adminArea4":"",
                   "adminArea4Type":"County",
                   "adminArea3":"Pichincha",
                   "adminArea3Type":"State",
                   "adminArea1":"EC",
                   "adminArea1Type":"Country",
                   "postalCode":"170206",
                   "geocodeQualityCode":"B1AAA",
                   "geocodeQuality":"STREET",
                   "dragPoint":false,
                   "sideOfStreet":"N",
                   "linkId":"0",
                   "unknownInput":"",
                   "type":"s",
                   "latLng":{
                      "lat":-0.092018,
                      "lng":-78.449836
                   },
                   "displayLatLng":{
                      "lat": 'latitudX',
                      "lng":'longitudX'
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
    json['results'][0].locations[0].adminArea6
```

para el ejemplo que usas seria

```
responseJson['results'][0].locations[0].adminArea6.toString()
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero por favor considera leer [answer]. Entiendo que puede ser sencillo para quien tiene experiencia, pero recuerda que la respuesta no sólo le servirá al OP sino a todo aquel que lea posteriormente la misma. Nadie te cobrará por agregar una lineas explicativas sobre la solución adoptada. Saludos